# Should we minify Cordova source files?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, minify, bundling-and-minification

I am using Cordova to build an android app (.apk).

I would like to keep the app size as small as possible. Should I minify the .html, .css, and .js files as well as the files of the various plugins I am using, with some third-party web sites such as https://www.minifier.org/   ?

Does Cordova minify those files automatically for us?

What is the best way to go about app minification in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered [this handy plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-minify) specifically for this purpose.

It is somewhat outdated. To use it, I made the following modifications in [PROJECT]\hooks\after_prepare\minify.js:

1) LINE 5:

```
var UglifyJS = require('uglify-js');
```

to

```
var UglifyJS = require('terser');
```

then installed that plugin with npm.

2) LINE 7:

```
var ImageMin = require('image-min');
```

to

```
var ImageMin = require('imagemin');
```

3) LINE 101:

```
    platformPath = path.join(platformPath, platform, "assets", "www");
```

to

```
    platformPath = path.join(platformPath, platform, 'app', 'src', 'main', 'assets', 'www');
```

Minifying the files in www/, www/css/, www/js, www/img/ and www/library/, It shrank my .apk file from 6.50MB to 5.94MB. Note that the last path was custom-added by me in LINE111 of minify.js.